# Rails authentication system for web and API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am looking for an authentication system for Ruby on Rails. However there seems no gem that supports both direct web authentication (e.g. like devise does) and API authentication (like devise_token_auth). The both I mentioned seem incompatible to each other (at least I got some errors after adding the devise_token_auth to a project with devise already set up). Devise used to have an API authenticable but it was removed (there's probably a good reason for that, however I couldn't find one online).

Is there any gem that can do both of those methods (web and api), or do I need to build some JavaScript based solution, like in the ng-token-auth Live Demo?

I won't reject a JavaScript solution as long as it doesn't dramatically increase load times or is hard to understand/customize. I just can't believe there is no solution to such a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

I took a closer look at devise_token_auth and together with ng-token-auth it seems to solve my problem.

So it seems I'll need to learn working with AngularJS for that, but that should be fine.